# Better way of implementing regex in Android

Tags: android, regex

I’m working on an app that requires to take some of the information in the incoming text messages, but the informations are not static they change in size and content. How properly execute that task in Android, I have tried using regex and partten methods but the results are not so much relabel. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

For example in Koltin you have to use it like :

> ```
>                 val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}")
>                   val matcher = pattern.matcher(message)
> ```
>
> Where regex is : ("\d{6}")

**Update** : you can follow also [this link](https://regex101.com/) to customize yours.